# c# - how to go about having a global list?

Tags: c#

I am learning C#, and have a question I can't find the answer to anywhere.

So let's say I have a list, it's called GunList.

```
List<string> GunList = new List<string>();
```

And since I know C# is an OOP language, what's the best way to access this list in different classes? Is it bad to make public static classes?

Comment: By "public static classes" do you actually mean "public static variables"?

Comment: Its bad to have things public and static that don't need to be if that is what you are asking, very broad to give a specific answer though

Comment: You have to clearify a few things on your class-design first: how many instances exist of these classes and in which relation are they? Has any instance its own list?

Answer (score 5):

The correct answer will depend on your OO design.  Don't just think about `GunList` but about what objects will interact with it, their multiplicity (one or many), and who might "own" the GunList etc.

If you get your OO design well structured then the right place for your GunList should become obvious.  Chances are you will find that you will want to define it in a class (i.e. not global statically) and pass it into a limited number of other objects.  This way you will minimise the "exposure" of GunList to other classes/instances (which is a good thing)

Comment: is it bad if I have a public static class called "globalvars", and have all my variables being set and received in it?

Comment: That approach defeats the whole point of OO programming for the reasons I've already stated.  Technically, this is possible but it isn't scalable and you can end up with just a big mess of globally accessible objects which becomes harder and harder to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

It's not generally an "OOP" thing to use a global static variable, but sometimes it is useful

Assuming that your OO design really makes sense for this to be treated as a global variable, consider wrapping it in a class anyway to take advantage of encapsulation and provide for any necessary logic in it's handling.

<strike>The singleton design pattern describes handling both of these needs together.</strike>

Modern C# static classes do the job in this case.

Essentially you have a static class for GunList that has a static accessor (Guns) to access the single static definition of the list, that can be used globally.

```
public static class GunList
{
    private static readonly List<string> gunList = new()
    {
         // Initialize here
    }
    public static List<string> Guns { get => gunList; }
}
```

Access it using

```
GunList.Guns
```